# How to run pg_dump? It fails with "pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: Р?РЁР?Р'"

Tags: postgresql, dump

How to get new dump? Worked well, but current fails with (DDL was generated using Hibernate):

````
Password:
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: Р?РЁР?Р'Р?Р?:  Р?РчС' Р?Р?С?С'С?РїР° Рє С'Р°Р+Р>РёС┼Рч address
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE public.address IN ACCESS SHARE MODE```
Failed on table:


CREATE TABLE public.address (
    id int8 NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp NULL,
    updated_at timestamp NULL,
    first_line varchar(255) NULL,
    second_line varchar(255) NULL,
    created_by_id int8 NULL,
    updated_by_id int8 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT address_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_hc8oul9dk1w3eqvro4go5fktk UNIQUE (second_line),
    CONSTRAINT fk595v9ynufg5bhir8havm099tr FOREIGN KEY (updated_by_id) REFERENCES user_account(id),
    CONSTRAINT fke3g20g1qymd4kdkik3ub58eam FOREIGN KEY (created_by_id) REFERENCES user_account(id)
);
````

Comment: Looks like your shell has a non-English UTF-8 locale configured, but your terminal doesn't know it. Either configure your terminal to support UTF-8 or change your locale to English.

Comment: Switched everything to USA (region, etc.). Did not helped.